# Trac not showing git branches

Tags: git, trac

I have Trac running with a git repo - all was working well until I created a couple of branches - Master & Develop.

Now the browse source doesn't show any updates. It does have the dropdown selector to choose a branch or tag - my branches and tags show up there. But if you choose one, it comes up with a message like this:

```
Error: No such changeset
No changeset 6a82ccb05334c19a997f666199bf876122d6b300 in the repository
```

What's going on? Do I need to do 'something' when I create a branch so that Trac can view the changes?

Mostly this would be useful if the timeline was getting updated (it was before I created any branches)

Comment: Trac doesn't support Git by default, so this issue is related to a Trac plugin, right? I suggest to ask the plugin author/maintainer directly, i.e. via *th-users* mailing-list or open a ticket against the plugin at trac-hacks.org (for externally hosted plugins at the associated tracker instance, of course). To enable the developer to give you substantial feedback you should include more details like exact Trac and plugin version/revision IDs and relevant Trac log output while the environment is in DEBUG logging mode.